# AngularJS otherwise route using parameters?

Tags: angularjs

Tried to use parameters in the Otherwise route, but failed.

Is there something wrong with the code below?

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/defaultRoute/:param1/:param2' });
```

Comment: I don't think otherwise would take parameter, because one never explicitly goes to otherwise route, so that route cannot be constructed and hence parameters cannot be passed.

Comment: give some examples of how URLs should be redirected

Comment: How would the parameters even be set?. I agree with @Chandermani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You cannot use **otherwise** with routeParams, use **when** instead.

If you want to redirect **'/*/:param1/:param2'** -> **'/defaultRoute/:param1/:param2'**

```
$routeProvider.when('/:all/:param1/:param2',{redirectTo: function(routeParams){
  return "/defaultRoute/" + routeParams.param1 + "/" + routeParams.param2;
}});
```

If you want to redirect **'/:param1/:param2'** -> **'/defaultRoute/:param1/:param2'**

```
$routeProvider.when('/:param1/:param2',{redirectTo: function(routeParams){
  return "/defaultRoute/" + routeParams.param1 + "/" + routeParams.param2;
}});
```